# Storing User Activities In CouchDB

Tags: logging, couchdb

I am new to CouchDB and to these type of databases so I have a question: How should I store every user's activity? I thought about storing it as an attachment, storing it in a different db using user id from user db. These would work somehow but don't seem to be efficient. I am trying to develop a tracking app therefore data will grow very fast. I have to develop a database that I can manage and track easily. What are your suggestions for storing user activity in CouchDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a separate database from your main database, then storing each activity as a single document in that database. You can then write map/reduce views to query it as needed.

So if your main database is call "foo", create another database called "foo-activity". Then add activity documents into "foo-activity" like this:

```
{
  "user_id": 4242,
  "activity": "clicking",
  "url": "http://foo.bar",
  "timestamp": 121212213
}
```

Then an activity_by_time_and_user view might look like:

```
function(doc){
  if doc.activity and doc.user_id
    emit([doc.timestamp,doc.user_id], doc.activity)
}
```

Then you can search by users based on a timerange.

Comment: This is what I am currently using now, I was having second thoughts about searching if database gets larger. But apparently I did not consider search based on timerange. So thanks!